# How to find out the internal microphone's driver on a Linux PC?

Tags: drivers, microphone

Every hardware device ( incl. the internal microphone, I suppose ) works under some driver.

How to find out which is the specific driver controlling the work of the internal microphone on a PC that works under Linux?

Comment: Sound is controlled by the ALSA drivers. First step is to look at the sound cards you have (`cat /proc/asound/cards`) and identify the one your internal microphone belongs to. Chances are high it's an Intel HDA, the kernel modules for that start with `snd_hda_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lspci -v
```

Lspci is a command on Unix-like operating systems that print a "list" of detailed information about all buses and PCI devices in the system.

output:

> 01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar
>   HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300/7300 Series]  Subsystem: XFX Pine
>   Group Inc. Cedar HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300/7300 Series]     Flags:
>   bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29    Memory at f7e40000
>   (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]     Capabilities: 
>     Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel     Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

Comment: part of the output from 'lspci -v':00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2281
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
 Memory at b5610000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

            where in the file system of my pc can I find the 'snd_hda_intel'-driver?